# Gearing change on Mongoose Malus

Tags: gears, fatbike

I recently purchased a Mongoose Malus, I would like to change out the front gear so I have a true granny gear (ie really low gear) and am not concerned with the top end speed.

Where can I purchase and what is recommended and how difficult will this be? This bike is mostly used around the ranch at very slow speeds in sand, grass, gravel and rocky areas mostly not even on a path.

[image]

Comment: Does the chain ring unbolt?   If not you need to change out the whole crank.

Comment: whats a "true granny"??

Comment: My terminology for low low gearing.

Comment: Whatever you replace - keep the old parts stored, so that you have the option of reverting later as your legs grow stronger.

Comment: @BenPoulter A granny gear is a really low gear, and a true granny gear is one that truly deserves to be called that.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a clearly written spec page for this bike, but based on the picture your easiest change will be to swap out the cassette/freewheel for a 7 speed with a larger number of teeth.

The question is whether the rear derailleur can fit a larger gear.

You'll also need a new chain to add more links.

Your other option is to replace the whole front chainring assembly with a smaller one.   At this price point there's a good chance its a common square taper fitment, so you might even be able to rescue a smaller crank off a donor-bike.

You could even use a triple crank off a MTB but only hook the chain onto the middle or little ring.   This would be the most economical option, the only bike-specific tool you need is a crank puller.

Comment: Why cant he just change the front chain ring to a highertoothed one? it should be normal mountain bike chainring specs, just go to a bike shop and have them find or order you a larger one. Mongoose wouldn't use a crank that didn't fit standards would they?

Comment: @JohnBurgess he wants a granny gear, which means a smaller tooth count chainring.  Yes it should work fine.

Comment: Oh duh. I will say I have replaced mountain bike cranksets with BMX style cranksets in the past. this allows for much smaller front chainrings. You could look into that as the best alternative